# How menu links works in joomla and how it's built on the page?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, joomla, menu

I was looking for a way to handle menu trees in a JPA 2/hibernate implementation solution and stumbled upon this [link](http://docs.joomla.org/Tables/menu) it outlines clearly the backend structure of joomla menu and i would like to base my own on it. Just that there are some part i don't understand very well.
On the table there are `level` and `ordering`, i would like to know the difference between them.

What comes to mind is that `level` sounds like the hierarchy for the menu as in `root menus for level 1` for example and `submenu for level 2` and `sub-submemu for level 3` and ordering  the sequence in which menu of the same level are shown.

I also would like to know how the `lft` and `rgt` are used ideally not a conceptual explanation but a practical one if possible.

Finally if I where to use JPA to fit this table structure what are the commons pitfalls and best practice. up to know, before discovering the `joomla` schema  i was interested in example shown in this [link](http://www.tikalk.com/java/load-a-tree-with-jpa-and-hibernate) .

thanks for reading this.

Comment: I have no experience with JPA what so ever but the 'rgt' and 'lft' fields is a part of the Nested Set Model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). I am pretty sure that your guess about ordering and level is correct.

Comment: thanks for the resource.+1 for that